# Questions about private mailbox address used for LLC in California

Tags: tax-law, banking

I recently created an LLC using a private mailbox to keep my home address private in public records (in California). I work from home so using my home address is not an option due to privacy concerns. The LLC has been filed and currently active so the Secretary of State allowed the private mailbox.

What's troublesome for me is when opening a business checking account I am not allowed to use a private mailbox address (according to Capital One) and instead I have to use my home address. Not only that, EDD (for state-level taxes in California) also did not allow private mailbox as the address so I had to use my home address there. I am okay with that since these are not being put to public records but I feel during tax season it will get very complicated as some documents will be using my home address and others the private mailbox address.

Capital One asked for my SS-4 which I provided but when I setup my EIN, I used my private mailbox as the business address so they are asking for other documents.

What should I do to open a business checking account? I was asked to provide 1 of these documents for proof:

> - Articles of Organization with members
> - Secretary of State filing with signer information
> - Operating Agreement
> - Articles of Formation
>
> Additionally, in order to verify the business address, we will also need one of the following documents:
>
> - Utility Bill
> - Proof of Insurance OR
> - Business License

Problem is, the first four bullet points uses the private mailbox address. The Utility Bill uses my home address but it doesn't have my business name just my full name. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: I'm not in CA. But I had a similar thing happen in OR. In the OR Articles of Organization there are 2 addresses - mailing address and physical address. Does CA not have that? Because my OR AOO had both, the bank had no problem with the varying addresses. (and for taxes I use the physical address.)

Comment: Try a bank or credit union other than Capital One.  They may not all have the same requirement, and I've had relatively bad experiences with Capital One on anything complicated, to the tune of many wasted hours.  (Admittedly on the consumer side.)

Comment: @SOIA The Articles of Organization has a mailing address field that was left blank, I used LegalZoom to set up my LLC. Even if I were to have a mailing address put on the form, wouldn't the Secretary of State still use the physical address for public records?

Comment: @TomW Thanks, I was thinking of trying American Express.

Comment: Yes. The SOS would use the physical address... my point was since my AOO had *both* addresses on it, my bank (Chase) had no issue setting up an account. A PO box should have never been put in place for a physical address, it should have been put in the mailing address spot. Sounds like LegalZoom didn't properly do the paperwork.

Comment: @SOIA but then how would someone who is working from home prevent their home address from being put into public records? From what I've read online, most people use private mailboxes to prevent others on the internet from looking up their home address.

Comment: You really can't hide your home address. Any illusion that it's not available is just that, an illusion. If I know your name, or your business name, I can find your physical address in a matter of moments and so can anyone else. While I use a PO box for business mailings, I really have never been concerned with my home address being public record.. I mean I purchased my house.. that's public record (and nothing to be done about it).

Comment: @SOIA Hmm I don't think it's that easy. How would you achieve such a thing if the business registered under a PO box/private mailbox? It's okay for you not to be concern but that's subjective. Purchasing a home and having it in public record is different from putting your home address as your business address because then you are associating your home address to all business matters. If you ever handled distraught customers it can get pretty ugly and I would like to feel protected from that.